# Не показывает владельца сервера на discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Вот есть код, для просмотра информации сервера:

```py
#информация о сервере
@bot.command(aliases = ['сервер'])
async def server(ctx):       
    embed = discord.Embed(
        description = f'**Информация о сервере** **{ctx.guild.name}**\n'
                      f'\n'
                      f'**Участники:**\n'
                      f'Людей: **{ctx.guild.member_count}**\n'
                      f'\n'
                      f'**Каналы:**\n'
                      f'<:channel:922373045165916180> Текствые: **{len(ctx.guild.text_channels)}**\n'
                      f'<:voice_channel:922373061146189864> Голосовые: **{len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)}**\n'
                      f'<:category:922376014091391018> Категории: **{len(ctx.guild.categories)}**\n'
                      f'\n'
                      f'**Владелец:**\n'
                      f'{ctx.guild.owner}\n'
                      f'\n'
                      f'**Уровень проверки:**\n'
                      f'{ctx.guild.verification_level}\n'
                      f'**Дата создания:**\n{ctx.guild.created_at.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}\n',
                     color=ctx.author.color,)
    embed.set_footer(text = f'ID: {ctx.guild.id}')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = str(ctx.guild.icon_url))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

И почему то всё работает, кроме этой строки:

```py
{ctx.guild.owner}
```

Вот так выглядит команда в дискорде:
[image]

Помогите пожалуйста сделать так, чтобы владельца показывало корректно

Comment: У меня Ваш код работает. Возможно у бота нет нужных разрешений.

Comment: [**Намерения**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) выданы?

Comment: А какое права нужно выдать для просмотра владельца?

Comment: По ссылке выше перейдите, сделайте как в инструкции и затем выдайте намерения боту в [коде](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0). Прочитать зачем нужны намерения можно все по той же ссылке выше